# SqlDependency.Start method fails after deployment

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, sqldependency

After implementing caching for my ASP MVC 5 app, and using SqlDependency and service broker, everything works fine on the local database. I get notifications when a specific change occurs in the database.

However, after deploying the application to production machine, call to SqlDependency.Start(string connectionString) fails by throwing an exception:

```
 System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user 'sa'.
```

with the following stack trace (system calls included, calls within my app code - excluded):

```
[SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user 'sa'.]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +6749670
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +815
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) +4515
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj) +84
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK) +53
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +368
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +6777754
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +6778255
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData) +878
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +1162
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +72
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +6781425
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection) +103
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +2105
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +116
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1089
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +6785863
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +233
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +278
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +239
```

Since the local and production database are kept in sync (and one was initially restored from the other one) DB settings are the same - I checked this to be sure, though.

I'm quite certain that service broker is enabled for the production DB.

What kind of IIS configuration should I consider important, which may cause this difference? I'm using Sql Server Express at the moment. Also, I don't use SqlCacheDependency but only SqlDependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a Service broker issue.

The error is: Login failed for user 'sa'

Check your connection credentials. Does your app allow the credentials to be modified at run-time? I'd recommend you do allow flexible configuration at deployment.

Even if you checked, can you guarantee that the deployment **SQL server** instance has the same SQL credentials, this may be the case even if you restored your development database.

Comment: DB credentials are not modified anywhere in the application. Also notice, that the same connection string (which is passed to SqlDependency.Start) with the same credentials is used on ASP server for all access to the DB. Everything else on the website works as expected, apart from views which refer to the cache (SqlDependency is to know when cache entry expires). Associated controller action is where the SqlDependency.Start is called and where it fails.

Comment: Are you certain the connection string in SqlDependency.Start(connectionString) is the same as used elsewhere? When SqkDependency fails you get errors along these lines: The SQL Server Service Broker for the current database is not enabled

Comment: Also check whether you are using integrated security.

Comment: I take the connectionString from `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` and it is truly different from the connection string in web.config, even though I am absolutely sure this connection string is not being modified at runtime. However, there is a difference - the `SqlConnection.ConnectionString` does not contain the hard-coded password, which is present in web.config. As I see now, and as I could have seen before, this is by design for security reasons. Integrated security is used on local machine, that's why it does not throw. On production machine password is required.

Comment: So, again, I'd recommend you allow configuration or, type in the right credentials. The error is a SQL connection error, not Service Broker/SqlDependency

Comment: Could you be more specific what you mean by configuration here? What exactly is to be configured?

Comment: If there's a possibility that your will be deployed to a server where you need different sql configuration ( connection settings), you need some way of changing that after deployment. So the connection string could be configured based on the production server settings.

Comment: As far as I understand we do have this sort of configuration, which caused the application to behave differently before and after deployment. I was attributing this misbehavior to the wrong subsystem, though.